# How should I care for this houseplant to prevent wilting?

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants, plant-care, wilt

Is anyone familiar on the name of this plant?
I seem to have problems with it wilting during the day, with or without sunlight.
I water this regularly during the day and started applying complete fertilizer when I noticed watering it regularly does not help it from wilting down.

Any suggestion on proper caring for this plant?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

It looks like [*Dracaena fragrans* 'Massangeana'](http://www.dracaena.com/dracaena-fragrans-massangeana.php) - one that hasn't formed a woody trunk yet. The reason it's wilting during the day is the sunlight - these plants do not appreciate direct sun. Dappled sunlight (like that beneath a tree canopy) is okay, but not full on sunlight. If you can, move it somewhere it gets bright daylight, but no direct sun, or very little sun, maybe just an hour at the end of the day. If you have no place out of direct sun, then try to arrange some shading for it. The other possible causes are temperature fluctuation, they prefer a stable temperature always above 17 deg C, and possibly excessive wind exposure. Hopefully there's a drainage hole in the bottom of that pot too...